# Randomly placing nonoverlapping unit cuboids

Tags: pr.probability, discrete-geometry, open-problems, packing-and-covering

Suppose one places unit cuboids of dimension $d$ with min-corners
uniformly distributed to lie in $[0,n]^d$, but with cuboid (strict) overlap forbidden.
At some point, the region is "saturated," without room for more cuboids to fit.
For example, for $d=2$ squares in $[0,10]^2$, it appears that about $63$ squares
on average will fit (whereas $n^d=100$ could fit):

---

[image: CubesPacking10]

---

So here the packing density is about $63$%.

> **Q**. Is the expected number of cuboids known, as a function of $n$ and of $d$?
>   Is the growth rate in $n$ known for fixed $d$?

---

**Update**. *Benjamin Dickman* identified the $d=1$ version as the 
[Rényi parking problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html),
where it is known that, for large $n$, the packing density approaches
$m \approx 0.7476$, i.e., the expected number of cars(intervals) is $m n$.
It is conjectured that in $d=2$, the expected packing density 
approaches $m^2 \approx 0.559$.

*Yoav Kallus* points to a related paper that uses the apt phrase 
*sequential random packing* for the process.

Comment: Is it possible that you are asking a question equivalent to an extension of the parking problem? Cf. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RenyisParkingConstants.html

Comment: A (1) discrete version (2) on a torus (3) in higher dimensions is treated in this preprint: http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0839 . Maybe it could be informative despite the many differences.

Comment: More generally, I believe what you want is the *random sequential adsorption* for *a system of parallel cuboids*. Here is a brief paper that refutes the $d=2$ (Palasti) conjecture (as do several other numerical works) and provides some citations/terminology that you may find of interest: http://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.631